# Access Private Framework 's class not having shared Instance iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, frameworks, iphone-privateapi

I am new to accessing private API.

Using following way to use the methods inside the class.

```
 NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework"];
 BOOL success = [b load];

 Class FTDeviceSupport = NSClassFromString(@"FTDeviceSupport");
 id si = [FTDeviceSupport valueForKey:@"sharedInstance"];

 NSLog(@"-- %@", [si valueForKey:@"deviceColor"]);
```

This "**FTDeviceSupport**" is having +SharedInstance method.

I wanted to Use `CallHistory` frameworks for the `CallHistoryDBHandle` class, Which is not having any sharedInstance so, Is that possible to access that from any other way ?
Please help me . Thanks.

Comment: not perfectly but I can call that method by creating instance of the class fetchedfrom string. But most the methods are giving null (nil) for ios9 . which currently I have tested. can you provide any help ? @FireCandy.

Comment: Ammm...Actually i have the same problem..finding way with no luck..:( please refer me if you got any solution...Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @Esha-can u help newbie with this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349278/how-to-add-only-unique-string-objects-to-nsmuatablearray-in-ios

Comment: @JIGAR Question has been removed

Comment: @Esha-Somebuddy has marked it as duplicate,So :(,Anyways can you give me any refrence for datewise header section tableView?same way like our contactbook?

Comment: @esha-I am new to ios and need help,i am making a tableView wit custom cell containing 4 labels,My problem is all cells are juggled when i am scrolling it up and down..:( can u help me for this?pls..!!!help appreciated frend.

Comment: @JIGAR Add this as a new question to stack . dont mix up all queries

Comment: @esha-ohk...sorry and thanks..good day

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563544/xmpp-change-password-in-ios-not-working